# Corrupted Repos

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, repository

I have a problem in updating my repos on 14.04. Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal I get

```
Fetched 30,4 MB in 36s (844 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-   updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to delete the lists and perform update but not working! Any ideas?

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Apt source lists are taken from `/etc/apt/source.list` and `/etc/apt/source.list.d/FILENAME-ENDING-WITH.list`. I think perhaps the folder you're looking at autogenerates from those .list files.

Hash sum mismatch suggests that the files at de.archive.ubuntu.com may be corrupted or that your versions being received over your internet connection are at least. FWIW:

```
k1210:~/tmp$ curl http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en | md5sum --
```

gives me an md5 of:

```
d47626f83d42df1f5feccac4697fa4e5
```

which matches what I get from the de archive (at http://u-1.mirror.tudos.de/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en).

Try altering de.archive.ubuntu.com in sources.list to point to an alternate mirror, eg fr.archive.ubuntu.com. Rerun `sudo apt-get update`. If it still fails post the full output somewhere (eg http://pastebin.com).